# Unity 3D на Linux Mint 20 розовый экран

Tags: unity3d, ubuntu

Установил Unity 3d на Linux mint Cinnamon 20. После запуска открывается окно с панелью вверху и заполненным содержимым
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Видюха не может отрендарить шейдеры .

Comment: Как решить проблему

Comment: вероятнее всего проблемы с драйверами

Comment: если не поможет, то решается заменой видеокарты на ту, которая нормально поддерживается твоим линуксом

Comment: Или можно просто не маяться хернёй с линуксом. Ну серьёздно... какая функция?

Comment: @Yaroslav ну в линуксе есть свои плюсы. Например чувство собственной гиковости)))

Comment: С ужасом вспоминаю времена когда на работе заставляли сидеть под убунтой. Стабильный релиз, свежая установка - не работает переключение раскладки клавиатуры по горячих клавишах, таск менеджер неправильно показывает количество занятой оперативки и половина прог которые нужно ставить ставятся исключительно с бубном через гугление.... это ппц.

Comment: @Andrew, нормальные люди, ублажают свое самолюбие банальной дрочкой без изврашений с применением стороннего ПО)))

Comment: У меня все проще, я занимаюсь разработкой под линукс уже более 5 лет и очень привык к системе и отвык от windows. А unity3d решил поставить, так, чтобы в свободное время и в ней что-то мутить. А на винду не поставить ее, так как у меня ее просто нет, а ставить пиратки надоело, так как все глючные